# Removing BOOTMGR from USB flash drive

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

Got 8GB flash drive. It was formatted to FAT32 and is completely empty, but windows shows that 4KB are in use (once formatted to NTFS windows shows that 54MB are in use).

Used some disk editing software to look inside. Turns out the space is taken by some BOOTMGR. As I understand this is only used if I would be booting something from this flash drive?

Any way to wipe it all? So that after format where would be no used space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/52129-disk-clean-clean-all-diskpart-command.html) is how to.

Note that the used space could be overhead of the filesystem. Check if formarting to FAT32 reduces the used space.

Answer (score 2):

For NTFS the space is always taken (by the Master File Table which is a special hidden file).
No way to make it really empty. You can vary the size of the MFT a little bit by using different parameters when formatting the NTFS partition.
(Windows uses a reasonably large MFT by default, which is nice on a normal harddisk with a general purpose usage-pattern, but sometimes is not very efficient on removable media, or on server-disks, that have a non-generic usage pattern.)

The term BOOTMGR is a red herring. That particular utility you used probably always calls the first sector of a disk BOOOTMGR, regardless what is really there.
Normally the first 512 bytes contain the partition table and (optionally) the first stage of the bootmanager. If the disk uses larger sectors than 512 bytes (4K in your case) the rest of that 1st sector is unused.

For FAT32 the first real useable block is actually the 2nd sector of the disk and that also will contain some file-system overhead. Ever folder takes some space. That also applies to the (empty) ROOT folder of the disk.

There is no way to have a filesystem to be 100% empty. Some overhead is always required.